# Copying text to clipboard using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In MS Excel 2010 I am trying to copy some text to the clipboard using `SendKeys`. However, it does not work.

Is this some kind of security measure that Microsoft took in order to prevent people from creating fraudulent macros? Here's some code that shows what I'm trying to do (assume, that you're in the vba window and have some text selected):

```
Public Sub CopyToClipboardAndPrint()
    Call SendKeys("^(C)", True)
    Dim Clip As MSForms.DataObject
    Set Clip = New MSForms.DataObject
    Clip.GetFromClipboard
    Debug.Print Clip.GetText
End Sub
```

Note that in order to use the MSForms.DataObject you'll have to reference `%windir%\system32\FM20.DLL` (i.e. Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library).

---

**Edit:**
The text I'm trying to copy is *not* in the document window, but in the immediate window of the vba project window! So Selection.Copy won't work here.

Comment: Any reasons why you can't call `Clip.SetText("Some Text", 1)` and `Clip.PutInClipboard`?

Comment: I don't know what `"Some Text"` is before run-time. I really need to GET the text that has been selected in the focused window.

Comment: Have you tried `SendKeys "^g^c"`?

Comment: I do select the immediate window with `"^g"`, yes. In a separate SendKeys I have tried `"^c"`, `"^C"`, `"^(c)"`, `"^(C)"`.

Comment: That works for me - do you manually select the text in the immediate window? Otherwise you could try `^g^a^c`.

Comment: It could be a bit off-topic but... if you have some data in immediate I guess you write it there from any other subroutine. Can't you catch this data before with any public variable instead of reading immediate window?? are you sure you explored all possible ways...

Comment: There definitely seems to be a better way than using the `Immediate` window, per @KazJaw.  You can catch this with a string variable, could be either public, or a local variable, and simply send that information to the other subroutines/functions, as needed.

Comment: Or, to phrase the question another way: How does this text *get* to the immediate window? If you have control over that, then you don't need to use SendKeys and you also won't need to use WinAPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code uses the SendInput function from the Windows API to simulate the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> key combination, in order to copy the current text selection to the Clipboard.

The copy/print subroutine (the very last procedure in the code) calls two utility functions to trigger the necessary key presses and then uses the code you prepared to retrieve the text from the Clipboard.

I've tested the code in the Immediate window, the code editor pane, and the worksheet.

```
  Option Explicit

  'adapted from:
  '  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/411552-sendinput-visual-basic-applications.html

  Const VK_CONTROL = 17       'keycode for Control key
  Const VK_C = 67             'keycode for "C"
  Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
  Const INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1

  Private Type KEYBDINPUT
      wVK As Integer
      wScan As Integer
      dwFlags As Long
      time As Long
      dwExtraInfo As Long
  End Type

  Private Type GENERALINPUT
      dwType As Long
      xi(0 To 23) As Byte
  End Type

  Private Declare Function SendInput Lib "user32.dll" _
      (ByVal nInputs As Long, _
      pInputs As GENERALINPUT, _
      ByVal cbSize As Long) As Long

  Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
      Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
      (pDst As Any, _
      pSrc As Any, _
      ByVal ByteLen As Long)

  Private Sub KeyDown(bKey As Byte)
      Dim GInput(0 To 1) As GENERALINPUT
      Dim KInput As KEYBDINPUT
      KInput.wVK = bKey
      KInput.dwFlags = 0
      GInput(0).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD
      CopyMemory GInput(0).xi(0), KInput, Len(KInput)
      Call SendInput(1, GInput(0), Len(GInput(0)))
  End Sub

  Private Sub KeyUp(bKey As Byte)
      Dim GInput(0 To 1) As GENERALINPUT
      Dim KInput As KEYBDINPUT
      KInput.wVK = bKey
      KInput.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP
      GInput(0).dwType = INPUT_KEYBOARD
      CopyMemory GInput(0).xi(0), KInput, Len(KInput)
     Call SendInput(1, GInput(0), Len(GInput(0)))
  End Sub

  Sub CopyToClipboardAndPrint()
      Dim str As String

      'Simulate control-C to copy selection to clipboard
      KeyDown VK_CONTROL
      KeyDown VK_C
      KeyUp VK_C
      KeyUp VK_CONTROL

      DoEvents

      Dim Clip As MSForms.DataObject
      Set Clip = New MSForms.DataObject
      Clip.GetFromClipboard
      Debug.Print Clip.GetText
  End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this, but this won't work in my case, because I'm not copying from the document (no cells selected). see my edit.

Comment: Please see my revised answer, Alexander.